# Vulkan - Get multiple queues from the same family

Tags: c++, vulkan

I am currently following the [vulkan tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/) series and stumbeled uppon this thing.

When the author introduces a second queue ([presentation](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Presentation/Window_surface#page_Creating-the-presentation-queue)) he creates `VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo` for every unique kind of queue family. But he always sets the `queueCount` property to `1`. Later, when getting the queue handles with `vkGetDeviceQueue` he has the third (`queueIndex`) parameter always set to `0`.

In the case that both graphics and present queue come from the same queue family, which is very likely to my understanding, are the two queue handles not the same. Since both point to  the queue in the `graphics` family at index `0`

```
VkQueue graphicsQueue;
VkQueue presentQueue;

vkGetDeviceQueue(device, indices.graphicsFamily.value(), 0, &graphicsQueue);
vkGetDeviceQueue(device, indices.presentFamily.value(), 0, &presentQueue);
```

And if that is the goal, why bother with having an "extra" present queue?
What could be the benefits from doing it like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the graphics queue may not support presentation, it's easier from a code perspective to not *assume* that the graphics queue and presentation queue are the same. Instead, this code assumes that they are different. It's OK to get the same queue more than once. It's called `vkGetDeviceQueue` rather than `vkCreateDeviceQueue` for a reason. The queue already exists; you're just getting a pointer to it.

This is also why there is no `vkDestroyDeviceQueue`.